# Compilation using Pi4j

Tags: java, gpio, pi4j

I run into the following problem: Upon running of the GPIO-example for my device built-in in Pi4J, I get an JNI error, followed by a NoClassDefFoundError for the com/pi4j/io/gpio/GpioProvider.
After some searching (both here and other websites) I came to the conclusion that I was missing the pi4j-gpio-extension.jar. Turns out I have to include these specifically while compiling. I was using:

```
pi4j --compile Gpioblabla.java
```

which is a macro/shorthand/dont know for

```
+ javac -classpath '.:classes:*classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/*' -d . Gpioblabla.java
```

This successfully compiles.
After running the program I get the NoClassDefError.
So the question is, how to explicitly include certain .jar files in pi4j/javac compilation?

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. You need to run it with the classpath as well. So run it like:

```
java -classpath '.:classes:*classes:/opt/pi4j/lib/*' Gpioblabla
```